# Change same digit with different digit in an array by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

By using Javascript I want to solve this problem. I have an array `[2,1,5,6,1,9,1]` and i want to change it like this `[2,0,5,6,0,9,0]` so where is 1 I want to change it in 0. I can understand this can be achieved by using for loop and if else but I want to know is there any more suitable method to do achieve that?

Comment: Have a look at [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if creating a new array is acceptable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If I use Array#map it will affect whole array I only want to change 1 digit on the places to zero.

Comment: Please try.. `console.log([2,1,5,6,1,9,1].map(x => x === 1 ? 0 : x));` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). But with conditional inside it. You can use ternary operation.

```js
function replaceAllOccurrences(arr, occr, rplcr){
  return arr.map(x => x === occr ? rplcr : x);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 2, 20, 6, 20, 2, 6, 2];

console.log(replaceAllOccurrences(arr, 2, 0));
```